# I need to send an api request to each cell of column A google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-speech-api

I am now using the manual method to send each request from column A
All I need is to send the same request to all cells of the same column, and the url must contain a variable for this cell

```
function aramex() {
sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("aramex");
var A2= sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
var url = "https://rahatystore.matjrah.store/api/rest_admin/orderhistory/";
  var payload = {
      "order_status_id": 20,
      "notify": 0
    };
  var headers ={
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Bearer token"
  }
var options = {
  "method": "put",
  "headers": headers,
  "payload": payload
};
let response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+ A2, options);
```

[sheet img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZhYs.png)

The same method, but for each cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function aramex() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("aramex");
  const sr = 2; //data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const url = "https://rahatystore.matjrah.store/api/rest_admin/orderhistory/";
  var payload = {
    "order_status_id": 20,
    "notify": 0
  };
  var headers = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer token"
  }
  var options = {
    "method": "put",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  };
  vs.forEach(r => {
    let resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + r[0],options);

    //rest of code
  })
}
```

Second question something like this:

```
function aramex() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("aramex");
  const sr = 2; //data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const url = "https://rahatystore.matjrah.store/api/rest_admin/orderhistory/";
  var headers = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer token"
  }
  vs.forEach(r => {
    var payload = {
      "order_status_id": r[2],
      "notify": 0
    };
    var options = {
      "method": "put",
      "headers": headers,
      "payload": payload
    };
    let resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + r[0], options);

    //rest of code
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much
The code works successfully 
One last question please
If I need to pass a value from column B
But this value is bound to the same value in column A
For example
The quantity for the order number in column A

But this value is in payload
in "order_status_id": 21,

Comment: You would have to redefine the payload inside the forEach loop order_status_ id = r[1];

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and the most wonderful answer
With all my heart, thank you